# MongoDB document traversal with Jongo

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection containing objects like that:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51acfe570e88060906797af8"),
"address" : {
    "street" : "10 rue des Lilas",
    "street2" : "",
    "city" : "Paris",
    "zipCode" : "75017",
    "country" : "France",
    "loc" : {
        "lat" : 0.0,
        "lon" : 0.0
    },
    "countryCode" : "FR"
}
}
```

I am trying to get the value of the address.street key with this code:

```
collection.find().map(r -> r).forEach(r -> {
            Object value = r.get("address.street");
            System.out.println("value is: " + value);
        });
```

I am getting null values, how can I get the real values?

*edit*: For the one giving -1 and not answering the question, and the others maybe, I do not want a solution with a java.util.Map, I want a really basic solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data for a very basic solution, creating a repository and the related entity class.
To fetch all the addresses you can use repository.findAll() and for querying by a specific attribute findByAttributeName would be sufficient.

For comprehensive documentation

https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface AddressRepository extends MongoRepository<Address, String>     {

    public List<Address> findByCity(String city);
    public List<Address> findByZipCode(String zipCode);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, unfortunately for this project I must work with Jongo.